# send list data from angular to django rest

Tags: angular, api, django-rest-framework

I am learning angular now i want to send array of data to django rest framework i tried using `HttpParams`,`JSON.stringyfy()` but nothing works data is going null

Angular code :

```
public getSymptomsList(symptomList:string[]){
    console.log(symptomList)

    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.ApiUrl}diagnos/`, {PASS_DATA_HERE},{headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Token ${this.AuthToken}`),});

  }
```

Djnago API code:

```
class diagnos(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        symptomlist = request.POST.getlist('symptoms')
        print(symptomlist)
        ...
```

but when I tried using terminal by `httpie` it gives results:

```
bhupesh@Laptop:~$ http -f POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/diagnos/ symptoms='fever' symptoms='urinoma'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: POST, PUT, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 5037
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2020 13:38:57 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.5
Vary: Accept, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY

[
    {
        "name": "uncoordination"
    },
    {
        "name": "fever"
    },
    {
        "name": "pleuritic pain"
    },
    {
        "name": "snuffle"
    },
    {
        "name": "throat sore"
    },
    {
        "name": "malaise"
    },
    {
        "name": "debilitation"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try to convert your request to this:

```
public getSymptomsList(symptoms:string[]){

    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.ApiUrl}diagnos/`, {symptoms},{headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Token ${this.AuthToken}`),});

  }
```

with this code the body will be an object with field symtoms something like this

```
{
"symptoms": ["a","b","c"]
}
```

Comment: what do you see in the network tab when the request is done

Comment: request goes successfully even i printed request.body in it prints list but it isn't going as post data